# TypeLit from generic Integer expression

Tags: haskell, ghc

The only way I know to construct a `Nat` is to use `-XDataKinds` with promoted integers, i.e., `type MyInt = 10 :: Nat`.

Instead, I'd like to have a function

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer
```

that I can index with a reflected `Nat`, and then *reify* the result. To demonstrate what I mean, assume some function `mkNat :: Integer -> Q Type`. I want to write

```
type Z = $(mkNat $ foo $ natVal (Proxy::Proxy 10))
```

(In my example, `foo` is fast enough that it can be computed at compile time without prohibitive overhead.) Having this capability saves me the multi-step process of running `foo` in a separate GHCi session, then copying the decimal representation of the result into a source file, and then compiling the code I really wanted.

Of course the only missing component is `mkNat`. If I write my own custom data type, the equivalent of `mkNat` is easy to write. But I'd really like to use the built-in TypeLits. Is there some TemplateHaskell (or singletons, or some other magic) that would allow me to reify an arbitrary `Integer` expression to a `Nat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits
import Splices

type Z = $(mkNat $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy 10))
```

And then:

```
module Splices where

import Language.Haskell.TH

mkNat :: Integer -> Q Type
mkNat = return . LitT . NumTyLit
```