# Type synonyms with TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

If I have a type `data Foo = Foo Int Int` where frequently (but not always) the second parameter is a (fixed) function of the first, I could write a helper function `mkFoo m = Foo m (f m)` to reduce duplication.

I have this exact problem, but at the *type level*. The natural solution might be to use singletons to promote `f`, but my `f` isn't easily promoted. Instead, I'm trying to use TemplateHaskell and reflection to evaluate `f` at compile time at the data level. For example, I can currently do this (using `‑XDataKinds` and `GHC.TypeLits`):

```
f :: Integer -> Integer

data Bar (a::Nat) (b::Nat)

mkNat :: Integer -> Q Type -- constructs a TypeLit

bar :: Bar 5 $(mkNat $ f $ proxy natValue (Proxy::Proxy 5))
```

It's obviously annoying to have to write this with a concrete type every time I want to use this pattern. Unfortunately, I know of no shorter or generic way to write the signature for `bar`.  In particular, I can't define the type synonym

```
type Bar' (m :: Nat) = Bar m $(mkNat $ f $ proxy natVal (Proxy::Proxy m))

bar :: Bar' 5
```

due to TH stage restrictions (`m` is not imported or known when compiling the synonym).

Is there any way to simplify the signature of `bar`?

Comment: You would have to write e.g. `mkBar n = appT (conT ''Bar) (litT $ numTyLit n) \`appT\` (litT $ numTyLit $ f n)` and then `bar :: $(mkBar 5)`. There really is no way to put a splice like that into a type synonym. Unless it is strictly *impossible* to promote `f`, then it will probably be easier to do so (even if it is non-trivial) than dealing with TH in the long term.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of your ultimate goal? Template Haskell always looks like line noise to me.

Comment: @dfeuer [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062614/typelit-from-generic-integer-expression) goes into a little more detail, but it's basically what I've got there. At the top level, when I give concrete types, I (frequently) want one type parameter to be a function of another. The function (`f` above) is too hard to compute in my head, so this turns into a multi-step process.